# Type 1&2 Errors in Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, logistic-regression

I have (1125660, 72) shaped data, and trying to train the model using Logistic Regression. My main focus on the prediction is to keep the type 1 (false positives) errors as low as possible, and when I changed the class_weight parameter to 'balanced' from the default None it helped a lot with my type 1 by cutting them in half (from 1000 to 500), but my type 2 error number has increased to 16000 from 500.

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)

# changed to
logreg = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced', max_iter=1000)
```

Since I pay more attention to type 1, I'm sure with using balanced weights, but trying to lower type 2 now, and make more true positive guesses. I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

#### What is `class_weight`

as you must have already known, it is the weight assigned to the samples according to their respective class. if set to `balanced`, then it uses inverse weighting so to speak:

> The “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as `n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`.

It seems you have a significant level of class imbalance in the favor of class positive, cause your FN has high rocketed after applying weights.

#### How to approach to the problem

I might say the issue of class imbalance and weighting is one thing, and error trade-off is another. by resolving imbalance (by over/under sampling or weighting) you are trying to improve you model generally. and you should do so, but not as a error trade-off tuning step, but for the sake of the model performance per se.

Afterwards, you can do your error trade-off tuning by plotting the ROC curve and choosing a threshold which satisfies your requirements regarding the errors. a common practice is to fix the desired error rate (here you've got FP to be as low as a value) then read the corresponding *other error type* from the curve

### Conclusion

First step is to do proper model training. your efforts regarding class imbalance and weighting as well as other considerations such as regularization and stuff goes here.

Then, after you did whatever you could to train a good model, you will read the ROC plot to find a threshold which satisfies your problem requirements. if the corresponding FN error rate is too bad for your desired FP error rate, it means the model is not as good as you want. it's a trade-off and the only way to solve it is to come up with a better model